# window does not update subview CGRect when changes orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In window screen  orientation works properly when i add subview in window orientation its not work for subview only. i Change subview CGRectMake when orientation.

```
self.myviewctrl = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYViewController"    bundle:nil];

if (InterfaceOrientation==LandScape) {
    self.myviewctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    self.myviewcrl.anothersubview.frame = CGRectMake(430, 0,50,320);
} else{
    self.myviewctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    self.myviewcrl.anothersubview.frame = CGRectMake(260, 0,60,411);
}

self.window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!self.window) {
    self.window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}
[[[self.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.myviewctrl.view];
```

Comment: I dont get that code. whats InterfaceOrientation and whats Landscape

Comment: if UIView is landscape means executes self.myviewctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
        self.myviewcrl.anothersubview.frame = CGRectMake(430, 0,50,320); otherwise executes else par..

Comment: that doesnt help ;) where do the values I mentioned come  from

Comment: I dont get that code meant more like: there is info missing

Answer (score 0):

Are

```
self.myviewctrl
```

and

```
self.myviewcrl
```

different viewControllers or it's just mistake in naming?